# How can I get the loop to work in my Java program?

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class TestingStuf2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            out.println("Enter a number");

            int number = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (number < 10) {
            if (number < 10) {
               out.println("This number is too small.");
               keyboard.nextInt();
           }else{
               out.println("This number is big enough.");
           }    
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }

}
```

I'm just having a little trouble looping this code. I've just started to learn Java a these loops have been confusing me the whole time. When  I run this program, if I enter a number less than 10 I get the message that says ""This number is too small" and then it allows me to type again. However if I then type a number greater than 10 I get the same message. Also, if the first number I enter is greater than 10, I get no message at all, the program just ends. Why is this happening?

Comment: You explained what behaviour you get - how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Be more clear about what happens vs what you expected to happen. As written, it's pretty hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have forgot to reassign the `number` variable. That's the reason why

> However if I then type a number greater than 10 I get the same
>   message.

Please try the code below. Thanks for @Dev.Joel's comment. I have modified the loop to `do-while` to suit the case better.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class TestingStuf2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            out.println("Enter a number");

            int number = keyboard.nextInt();

        do{
            if (number < 10) {
               out.println("This number is too small.");
               /*
                * You should reassign number here
                */
               number = keyboard.nextInt();
           }else{
               out.println("This number is big enough.");
           }    
        }while(number < 10);
        keyboard.close();
    }

}
```

I suggest you use `break point` to debug your problem. In your case, for example, you assign 2 to `number`, and "This number is too small" is printed. Next, you use `keyboard.nextInt()` to let user input another int. However, the number is still 2. Thus condition `number < 10` is true no matter what you input this time, and `"This number is too small"` is printed again.

Comment: if you enter a higher number first 10 never enters the while

Comment: @Dev.Joel Thanks for you kind remind. I will edit the answer.